# Using setw is failing inside of a for loop

Tags: c++

Suppose there is an array of structs called machine with elements drink, price.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << i+1 << ". " << machine[i].drink;
    cout << setw(20) << machine[i].price << "\n";
}
```

This isn't working the way I would normally expect setw to work, and it's formatting my spaces in much the same way that \t would do (not creating columns but rather uneven spacing).

Any help here?

Comment: Can you show the output you're getting, and the output you're expecting?

Comment: You're only setting the width on the last item on the line, if you want columns you need to set the width for the others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the width for the incorrect output.

As written, your `setw(20)` starts after the `machine[i].drink;` output.  So if you want to print `Coke` for `$1.00`, you'd see `Coke` followed by 15 fill characters for spaces, then `$1.00` as the last 5 characters of the `setw(20)`.  But if you wanted to print `Mountain Dew` for `$1.00`, you'd again see `Mountain Dew` followed by the same 15 fill characters, then `$1.00`.

What you need is the fill characters to be appended to the end of the `machine[i].drink` output, but currently you're putting them at the beginning of the `machine[i].price` output.

You should be using `setw()` on the first output and left justifying it.  Then output the price without a `setw()` or justification.

For example:

```
cout << setw(20) << left << i+1 << ". " << machine[i].drink;
cout << machine[i].price << "\n";
```